# tomar un dato de un select o un input dependiendo cual tenga el valor

Tags: php, html, mysqli

lo que quiero hacer es lo siguiente, tengo un form donde tengo un select option donde tengo varias zonas, y quiero agregar un input para cuando la zona que necesito no este en select agregarla, este es mi codigo que por lo visto no me sirve:

```
<select name ="zona">
            <option name="0">Busca tu zona aca</option>
          <?php
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM zonas";
            $query = mysqli_query($cnx, $sql);
            while ($r = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
              echo "<option value=".$r['id']." name=zona>".$r['zona']."</option>";
            }
          ?>
        </select>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="zona" placeholder="Si no esta tu zona en la seleccion">
        </div>
```

cual le doy a boton, si el dato esta en el input se agrega a la bd, pero si el dato esta en el select no me agrega nada a la base de datos, en que le estoy errando?

```
<?php
 $zona= mysqli_real_escape_string($cnx, $_POST['zona']);
 if (!empty($zona)) {
 echo "aca hay dato, este es el dato que hay: ". $zona;
 }else{
 echo "aca no hay nada";
 }
```

Comment: Podrias usar diferentes nombres y chequear si el `select` esta vacio.

Comment: Si puedes añadir el php para que veamos como recoges los datos y demás, sería de gran ayuda. Además en el <opction> te sobra el parametro name

Comment: Para poder ayudarte sería muy útil que muestres cómo recoges y/o envías los datos. El problema puede ser: un ´´input´´ tiene sólo un valor, en cambio un ´´select´´ puede estar cargado de valores[], por lo que debes capturar el valor seleccionado, de lo contrario se toman todos los valores[] y se produce el error.